# Display ADC result on LCD or Terminal using CodevisionAVR

Tags: avr, adc

My project is an audio spectrum analyzer, but I am stuck in displaying the ADC results, either on my LCD or on the Terminal of CodevisionAVR.

The project uses an ATmega16A, with an 7.37 MHz external oscillator. For an IDE I am using CodevisionAVR.

The audio spectrum analyzer takes its input through a 3.5 mm jack audio cable, this signal is amplified and filtered in order to select the frequencies between 0 and 4 KHz, and the output of this circuit is connected to PA0, which is the channel 0 of the ADC of the microcontroller.

For testing, I have set the ADC to work on 8 bits (read the most significant 8 bits), taking the internal 2.56V as voltage reference. I have decoupled AREF pin using a 10nF capacitor (I will change it to 100nF for a better noise reduction). The ADC is also in free running mode.

I am stuck in displaying the ADC results, either on my LCD or on the Terminal of CodevisionAVR (through the UART --- configured using the wizard).

This is the function I used for the ADC:

```
    // Voltage Reference: Int., cap. on AREF 
#define ADC_VREF_TYPE ((1<<REFS1) | (1<<REFS0) | (1<<ADLAR)) 

// Read the 8 most significant bits 
// of the AD conversion result 
unsigned char read_adc(unsigned char adc_input) 
{ 
    ADMUX=adc_input | ADC_VREF_TYPE; 
    // Delay needed for the stabilization of the ADC input voltage 
    delay_us(10); 
    // Start the AD conversion 
    ADCSRA|=(1<<ADSC); 
    // Wait for the AD conversion to complete 
    while ((ADCSRA & (1<<ADIF))==0); 
    ADCSRA|=(1<<ADIF); 
    return ADCH; 
}
```

Main function of the code:

```
void main (void)
{  

Init_Controller();  // this must be the first "init" action/call!
#asm("sei")        // enable interrupts
lcd_init(16);
lcd_gotoxy(0,1);
lcd_putsf("AUDIO SPECTRUM");
delay_ms(3000);
lcd_clear();

    while(TRUE)
    {      
        wdogtrig();

        TCNT1 = 0; //usage of Timer1 with OCR1A 
        TIFR |= 1<<OCF1A;
        for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
            while((TIFR & (1<<OCF1A)) == 0)  
            putchar(read_adc());
            //adc_set[i] = adc_read(); //this is a second option
            TIFR |= 1<<OCF1A;
        } 
        //for(i=0; i<N; i++)
            //printf("adc values: %d \n",adc_set[i]);
} //end while loop
}
```

N is defined as 32 = number of samples in 1 AD conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The first error I see is using putchar() to write a number to the LCD.

The result of read_adc() is a number, not a string of ascii characters. You need to use sprintf to write the ADC result as a string into a buffer, then use lcd_putsf() to send the buffer to the LCD.